# Add a configurable text before the webform

Tags: 7, blocks, webforms

I'm working with Drupal 7.

I created a webform content and I want to add a configurable text as an introduction before my form. It's not a textarea. It's just a simple text wich should be configurable from my admin.

I created a block wich contains my text and in **settings** > **Show block on some pages only** > I chosen **Only the pages listed** and set my link /content/add_project

But my text is not displayed.

Any idea please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a block for it. There is *markup* type field in the webform module you can use it for display informative or configurable text in the webform where you like to show. You can also use HTML for this.

**For Example**
[image]

For more details, [click here](https://d7help.appstate.edu/form-component-types/markup)

Answer (score 0):

In drupal 7 when specifying what page to put a block on dont have the starting slash. So if you've got the show on pages as:
/content/add_project

Change it to:
content/add_project

Comment: Thanks Sir, It works properly.. But I could not put my block between the title and the form.

Comment: Yes in the template the title it above the page content. If you want it directly on the form you could add a form element for markup (I think its called "markup" or "advanced text" but it effectively lets you display some text as a form element ). So the only downside is you will have to edit the form elements to change this text, rather an edit a block

Comment: Yes I did. I used markup and it solves my problem. Thank you..